# AttributeError: Event instance has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

I am trying to make a program that will return the user's input and also clear the `Entry` when Return/Enter is pressed. When ran, the second method (`def e_delete(e):`) always gives the error, `AttributeError: Event instance has no attribute 'delete'` and if the `e` is changed to `self` no string is returned and no error happens.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os.path
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk

def on_change(e):
    inp = e.widget.get()
    print inp

root = tk.Tk()

#Makes a canvas for objects
canvas = Canvas(root, height=100, width=400)
#Displays the canvas
canvas.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

label = Label(root, text="Enter an element or the atomic number from 1 to 118.").grid(row=0, column=2)

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind("<Return>", on_change)
e.grid(row=2, column=2)
e.focus()

def e_delete(e):
    e.delete(0, 'end')

e.bind("<Return>", e_delete)

#img = create_image(0, 300, 'ptable.png')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can we get a piece of code that doesn't throw 2 errors and a tkinter warning, please? In other words, an actual [mcve]?

Comment: Also, what's the question? And what does _"return the user's input"_ mean? Return it _where_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
def entry_delete(e):
    e.delete(0, 'end')
```

[The value that gets passed to a callback for an event binding is an `Event` object.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) And they don't have a `delete` method.

The fact that you also have a global variable with the same name doesn't make any difference (except to confuse you and other readers); the parameter `e` hides the global `e`.

So, if you want to call a method on your `Entry` object, don't hide it:

```
def e_delete(evt):
    e.delete(0, 'end')
```

Or, if you want to call a method on whatever widget triggered the event (which, in this case, will always be the same thing, so it's just a matter of which one makes more sense to you), you can do that instead:

```
def e_delete(evt):
    evt.widget.delete(0, 'end')
```

However, it's usually even better to give *everything* clear and distinct names to avoid this kind of confusion:

```
entry = tk.Entry(root)
ent.pack()
entry.bind("<Return>", on_change)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
entry.focus()0

def entry_delete(evt):
    entry.delete(0, 'end')

entry.bind("<Return>", entry_delete)
```

Comment: Thank you is much! Now is it possible to get the result from the user as well as delete the entry?